# Shift Concrete Column by few inches

Tags: concrete, foundation, column

While building the foundation of a house, the concrete columns were built 15cm (6 inches) from the planned position, which is reducing the space for a door.

So we need to shift the column by 6 inches. How to do it? It's built upto the ground level only yet, and beam isn't  built over it.

Please point me to an appropriate place to ask this, if this is not one for civil engineering questions. Thanks.

Edit: Adding pic. The position that should have been there is shown below. But, C2 is shifted to left by 6 inches, and the column shown at the bottom of pic is shifted 6 inches to right. This leaves no space for the door to be placed as expected. Need a workaround.

[image]

Edit 2: In below pic, the upper column is shifted to left by 6", and lower 6" to right, leaving just 2'6" for door rather than required 3'6".

[image]

Comment: A column normally supports a beam or arch carrying part of the load of a building. Are you sure this is what you mean? Concrete blocks or poured concrete next to a door frame are not necessarily columns.

Comment: Yes the column which is used to support the beam. It is just placed nearby the position of a door..that's another thing.

Comment: Is the other side of the door supporting anything?

Comment: Wait, I will add a pic of the plan to make it clearer.

Comment: Rather than shift it, could you pour or place an additional 6" alongside the existing column. Is the column visible so that adding to the existing column would be unsightly?

Comment: @ArchonOSX Added pic - kindly refer to it..thanks

Comment: Hmmm how about telling them to tear it out and out it where it was supposed to be or they don't get paid? Is that an option or was this a DIY project?

Comment: @JimStewart Sorry, I cannot understand how adding 6" will help.. Kindly refer to the updated pic in the question. The upper column is built 6" to left and lower one 6" to right..leaving no space for door.
Column isn't visible, but is of the same thickness as wall.

Comment: @ArchonOSX No it's not DIY project. Cannot tell them that they don't get paid, as the mistake was from my side - I had provided wrong dimensions in the Foundation Plan diagram - Measured from inner ends of columns rather than center of column, and told them that it's Center-to-center.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok how about changing the swing of the door? It would seem that if the only difference is it is moved 6" to the right then you still have the same size opening except it now has a corner in the way of the swing.

Comment: That might help, though not serve the purpose perfectly, but workable. 
More than this particular situation, there are two more places where this wouldn't help - there I need to shift the column [Adding those pics too].
Columns are built in straight lines to support beams..so there are are 4 more columns displaced like this, causing similar problems.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Added the pic of second situation, third one is also exactly like second one.

Comment: The columns are an integral part of the structure of the home. Moving them requires the knowledge of an engineer on site. There's not nearly enough information here for us to answer responsibly. If you'd like to revise to ask how to work around the columns as they are, that's a better question for this site.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, you're right. I couldn't find a Civil Engineering website of Stack Exchange, so posted here.

Answer (score 2):

I would just angle the wall instead and leave plenty of room for a door.

My OCD likes right angles too but there is nothing wrong with a wall that runs at an angle, especially in this case.

Good luck!

Comment: There's a shower to the left side of wall shown as B1 (Joining left end of door and the bottom column), so cannot angle the door in second case.

Comment: @kushpf: Are you planning on installing the shower 15cm to the right of the planned position to aligin with the misaligned column - this seems unnecessary.

Comment: No. There is a bathroom in left of the wall, so meant that door cannot be angled.